# Angular 1.5 dynamic components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components, angular-template

Using Angular 1.5;

I am moving to webpack and was having some trouble getting an ng-include to work on a template file.

I stumbled across this:
https://kamranicus.com/posts/2017-11-17-dynamic-angularjs-components

Which uses a component for each template and dynamically loads each component.

I have a few components defined:

```
angular.module('myapp')
  .component('fieldOne', require('./field.one')
  .component('fieldTwo', require('./field.two');

// field.one.js
module.exports = {
  template: require('./one.html')
};

// field.two.js
module.exports = {
  template: require('./two.html')
};
```

I then try to add those components dynamically:

```
// comps = ['one', 'two']
<div ng-repeat="comp in comps">
  <ng-include src="{{comp}}"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Is this possible in Angular 1.5?  Is this the right way to dynamically insert components in 1.5?

Not having any luck, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ng-include requires an html file location. From what I see now it will only get the name. Try to create html files where you render the component. For example one.html would have <component-one></component-one> etc

Comment: @Nat so how would I go about dynamically injecting <component-one> ?

Comment: You can compile it with $compile('<component-one>')($scope) and attach resulting element to DOM. If component list is expected to change dynamically (e.g. varying array with ng-repeat), I'd suggest to stick to ng-include.

Comment: @estus thanks. Trouble is I am trying to move away from ng-include as it doesn’t work great with Webpack. I know there are solutions for that but was trying to go with a component and hoping dynamically adding them to the dom would be easy. List of “types” is probably less than 10, so maybe just an ng-switch statement on type is best.

Comment: I don't see any problems with webpack here. You need to have their list as array constant, it's unnecessary to do `import * as components from "./components"` like in the article. Without ng-include you will end up reimplementing its functionality, you can check its source code. Yes, for limited amount of comps ng-switch would probably work best.